# Express not serving static files in public subdir

Tags: javascript, html, apache, express

I'm having several problems trying to serve static files in public subdirectories with Express and Apache.
My working path is the following:

- public

  - css

    - style.css
- app.js

app. js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

If style. css is inside the public folder everything's fine. If I move it into the css directory (changing the relative html tag), this is the error I get:

```
https://example.com/css/style.css 404 not found
```

This is the link in the html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

This is my apache server configuration :

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia Full
        <Proxy *>
            Require all granted
        </Proxy>

        <Location /*>
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
        </Location>
        <Directory "/var/www/">
            AllowOverride None
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Could it be a proxy issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I expected was an Apache configuration issue. As soon as I edit the configuration file as shown below, the public directory and its sub-dir "css" were identified correctly.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    <Directory "/var/www/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```